# Mixup between root and first non-root user account

Tags: debian, root

I just installed Debian Jessie and created a user account ("jerome") during installation.

I log into my server through SSH as jerome, then use su to work as root. (sudo is not installed and root ssh is disabled).

On my fresh install, I installed and configured etckeeper and smartmontools.

- When logged in as root, if I commit using `etckeeper commit`, the author of the commit is jerome and the committer is root. I'd expect both to be root.
- I configured smartmontools to send mails to root (using option `-m root`) but the mails are sent to jerome (in `/var/mail/jerome`).

I can't figure out any explanation for this and I can't find the right keywords to search.

In case it matters, the groups for user jerome are

`jerome cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev`

Comment: For `etckeeper`, are you sure you used `su -` rather than just `su`? For `smartmontools`, are you sure the mails are not simply being sent to `jerome` because there is a mail alias from `root` to `jerome`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/etckeeper) for `etckeeper`, your first situation is documented,

> commit [message]
>   Commits all changes in /etc to the repository. A
>   commit message can be specified. You may also use the underlying VCS
>   to commit manually. (Note that etckeeper commit will notice if a user
>   has used sudo or su to become root, and record the original username
>   in the commit.)

For the second, typical Debian behaviour is to alias root's messages to the first non-root user account created on the system. This can be found in `/etc/aliases`

> root: jerome

Comment: Thanks. If I had encountered only one of the two "issues", I would have searched specifically. But seeing both at the same time, I thought they were related somehow, which lead me to look for a system-wide explanation rather than a software feature. This etckeeper feature is great, in fact. I didn't know this was even possible.